# Conditionally convert to lowercase

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and attempting something which seems like it should be trivial, but has not been so far. 
I simply want to check if a string is lowercase, and if not then convert it to lowercase.

```
if (!user.getName().equals(user.getName().toLowerCase())){
  user.setName(user.getName().toLowerCase());
}
```

For some reason I'm getting an `null` as a result and I'm not sure why.

`getName` and `setName`:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: What is the username for which you are getting the unexpected result?

Comment: That `if` statement seems very pointless. Just convert to lowercase, instead of doing the check if it needs to be done by doing it and then seeing if it changed.

Comment: `testName` is the name I've been testing with.

Comment: What is the source code for you user getName and setName methods? Looks like they do something more than just assigning to a field.

Comment: `testName` will fail your `if` condition because it contains an uppercase character `N`.  Perhaps you want to revise your logic.

Comment: I'd think because of the `!`, `testName` would satisfy my `if`.

Comment: Please include enough code to have a [mcve]. It seems likely that the issue is in code we cannot see.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Your getter and setter look fine. Please add enough code that we can reproduce the `null` value.

Answer (score 4):

Fortunately, you do not have to do a check before the conversion, because Java already does it for you. When you call `toLowerCase`, the first thing Java does is checking if the string has any characters that need to be converted, as a matter of optimization. Therefore, all you need to do is

```
user.setName(user.getName().toLowerCase());
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't solve the problem with the `null` value.